# Interaction Trigger on usercontrol from Mainwindow.xaml not working

Tags: wpf

I have usercontrol in which I have a listbox and in my mainwindow.xaml I am using two usercontrols and trying to clear selectedItem of one listbox of usercontrol1 if usercontrol2 listbox item is selected and vice versa using interaction Trigger and viceversa.

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=usercontrol1}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When I try this in sample example directly having two controls it is working but with usercontrol selection not clearing.

Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nagasree.

Comment: What is working and what is not working?

Comment: If I directly use two listboxes and for them if I use Interaction trigger the selectedItem is cleared if I select in another list but if is use same trigger on usercontrol it is not working listbox present inside the usercontrol and I am giving interaction trigger on usercontrol.